# How to rewrite this generic arg?

Tags: generics, rust

In a function one should be able to send a `String` and receive `Vec<usize>` or `HashSet<i32>`. It is already working (see below):

```rs
fn line<T: FromIterator<A>, A: FromStr>(str: String) -> Result<T, &'static str> {
```

but, since it takes 2 generic args, you have to write something like the following:

```rs
line<Vec<usize>, _>()?;
```

Is there a way to write it with only one generic argument? Perhaps similar to:

```rs
// This doesn't work!
fn line<T: FromIterator<A: FromStr>>(str: String) -> Result<T, &'static str> {
```

The goal is to be able to write calls this way (only one generic):

```rs
line<Vec<usize>>()?;
```

> Docs: [std::iter::FromIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html), [Generic Types, Traits, and Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-00-generics.html), [Generic parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html), [Trait and lifetime bounds](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use an opaque `impl Trait`. [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=62a967447735a34cdcdb82e297e6ff0d)

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

fn line<T: FromIterator<impl FromStr>>(str: String) -> Result<T, &'static str> {
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    line::<Vec<String>>("".into());
}
```

See [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters).